# Creating a settings page for a VSTO custom ribbon add-in

Tags: outlook, vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin, visualdesigner

I'm making a custom add-in for Outlook 2013/2016 and decided to implement it with a custom ribbon button. I've followed this guide which has been good so far : https://timdams.com/2017/05/09/how-to-create-a-simple-outlook-vsto-addin-a-step-by-step-guide/

The add-in simply edits the "location" field of a new meeting request or appointment and inserts a pre-defined phone number (for a conference call etc).

I've got that part working with the click of a custom button in the ribbon, but the inserted phone number is hard coded. I'd like to make it customizable and create another button that brings up a "settings page" where a user can enter in their own phone number, save it, and then the add-in will use that number instead.

I'm having trouble finding resources on how to do this. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regular Winform. The only trick is to make sure it is parented correctly to the right Outlook `Inspector` or `Explorer` object - cast the appropriate object to `IOleWindow`, then call `IOleWindow.GetWindow`. Once you have `HWND`, you can use it with the `NativeWindow` object and pass it to `Form.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to VSTO development so I'm not understanding some of the terms you're using. I've got a Winform going in my project now (added as a new item), then I used the toolbox to add a text box and "save" button. Now how do I link it back to the ribbon button?

Comment: In the event handler, create a new instance of your form's class and use NativeWindow  to parent it to the correct Outlook window.

Comment: Thanks I've managed to code in the bulk of the functionality I wanted using a Winform. Although I didn't use any of the methods you suggested. I simply used the  `showDialog();` method to run on the button click to bring up the new form.

Comment: If you don't parent the form correctly, it might be possible to click on the Outlook window while you dialog is being modally shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating an adjoining Outlook form region for such purposes. So, users could easily edit the settings for new meeting requests or appointments. See [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019) for more information. Also, you may find the [Walkthrough: Design an Outlook form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-designing-an-outlook-form-region?view=vs-2019) article helpful.